# How can I import a Python module and have it work within my main file?

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to get **IsInRange()** to give me a `True` or `False` statement, but the module does not see the main file input. I keep getting

```
'NameError: name 'firstnum' is not defined'
```

**MODULE1**:

```
def IsInRange():

  if firstnum in range(lr,hr) and secondnum in range(lr,hr):

    return True

  else:

    return False
```

**MAIN**:

```
import MODULE1

lr = int(input("Enter your lower range: "))

hr = int(input("Enter your higher range: "))

firstnum = int(input("Enter your first number: "))

secondnum = int(input("Enter your second number: "))


MODULE1.IsInRange()
```

Comment: You have to pass firstnum and secondnum as arguments to the function `IsInRange()` thats why they are undefined

Comment: Functions don't automatically inherit variables from the caller.  As @tpaskowski said, you need to rewrite the function to accept those variables as arguments.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Is your function just for the sake of example? It could be simplified slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def IsInRange(firstnum, secondnum, lr, hr):
    if firstnum in range(lr,hr) and secondnum in range(lr,hr):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then to use the function, you would pass those values in:

```
MODULE1.IsInRange(firstnum, secondnum, lr, hr)
```

**EDIT**: FYI You also don't need the if else. You can just return the conditional

```
return (firstnum in range(lr,hr) and secondnum in range(lr,hr))
```

**Example**:

```
def IsInRange(firstnum, secondnum, lr, hr):
    return (firstnum in range(lr,hr) and secondnum in range(lr,hr))

>>> IsInRange(6,8,1,10)
True
>>> IsInRange(6,15,1,10)
False
```

Comment: You're discarding the return result of the function.

Comment: @JohnGordon not sure if I know what you mean. I meant simply returning the result of the `if` conditional is the same behavior, but more concise.

Comment: Your example call `MODULE1.IsInRange(firstnum, secondnum, lr, hr)` does not capture the return result.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean you're right, I was just following along with the question. I'm assuming the OP would either want to `print()` or set it as a variable for use later on. `result = IsInRange(6,8,1,10)`

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input. This worked for my intended purposes. I am still learning Python and there are a lot of gaps in my knowledge of the basics. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

def IsInRange(firstnum,secondnum)

if firstnum in range(lr,hr) and secondnum in range(lr,hr):